# Clear data when application close

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to save some data when i login to the application and once i kill the app user data and session should have to be clear.

I have tried some method in Xamarin essential but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Xamarin.Essential's [SecureStorage](https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage) and you can clear user data in android by overriding OnDestrory method. Clear the stored data in SecureStorage.

Comment: Thanks. I have saved username and token in Persistent data.

Comment: Since SecureStorage saving data in the encrypted matter, it is good to use to this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Also available for Java?